# I keep getting a bunch of numbers as my output in the console

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on this question:

Given a non-negative integer num, repeatedly add all its digits until the result has only one digit.

Example:

Input: 38
Output: 2
Explanation: The process is like: 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2.
Since 2 has only one digit, return it.

here is my code:

```
const addDigits = (num) => {
  
    while(num > 9){
      let strNum = num.toString()
      let count = 0;
      console.log(strNum)
      for(let i = 0; i < strNum.length; i++){
        count += Number(strNum[i])
      
        //while number is greater than 9 we have to keep going
        
      }
    
    }
    num = count
  console.log(num)
};
addDigits(38)
```

I keep getting a bunch of numbers in my console instead of the desired output. Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `num = count` at the end of each loop iteration, instead of outside the loop.

```js
const addDigits = (num) => {
  
    while(num > 9){
      let strNum = num.toString()
      let count = 0;
      console.log(strNum)
      for(let i = 0; i < strNum.length; i++){
        count += Number(strNum[i])
      
        //while number is greater than 9 we have to keep going
        
      }
      num = count; //moved to last statement of each iteration
    }
    
  console.log(num)
};
addDigits(38)
```